# What are the features/aspects/characteristics of any signal?

Tags: measurement, communication-standard

When Signal Processing experts measure signals, what are the features they measure in minimum (true to all signals)?

- **Time** (discrete/continuous)
- **Amplitude/magnitude/value** (discrete/continuous)
- **Frequency** (discrete/contnious)

Is this list correct and anyway is there anything else that Signal Processing experts measure for any given signal?

Comment: What is leading you to these definitional questions? Are you writing a book?

Comment: @DanBoschen no, it's basically the desire to understand what digital is in origin, right after the "etymological" analysis. This one word is one of the trickiest I came across, with almost anyone using it differing the meaning of its colleague, least level of agreement between users !

Comment: And a second motive, it's kind of an entertainment for me, a journey or an adventure, to finally find out what this word most commonly mean.

Comment: Yes and interesting where the "authority" actually lies in these definitions. It is not like there is one equivalent to Webster's Dictionary (that I know of) but more a collective understanding of the common use.  (And Webster's say digital its anything that uses electronics--- yet we can and do have analog electronics).

Comment: @DanBoschen one more thing, I teach elementary programming and webmastering and often pupils and wrote a small webpage about what digital is in an elementary explanation, I personally don't view my website as a book but one might do so, anyway this is the webpage: https://hanekudai.com/index.php/%D7%93%D7%99%D7%92%D7%99%D7%98%D7%9C%D7%99

Comment: ok that makes sense, I figured some kind of instruction was involved-- it leads to such questions we wouldn't otherwise have. I understand that- I teach as well and similar thoughts pop into my head (https://www.dsprelated.com/courses)

Comment: and often pupils ask about near terminology. I wrote*

Comment: @freesoftwareuser Cool website! Thank-you for sharing.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @PeterK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I consider "measure", I think of what test equipment would report about waveforms I am evaluating. For this purpose, the list in unbounded. Further for each of these there is no common denominator (no common set of low level "signals") that is used, as it is based on the sensor, which could be voltage, pressure, temperature, etc. I don't think we can bound the types of sensors that could possibly exist.

- EVM
- Insertion Loss
- Return Loss
- Current
- Voltage
- Frequency
- Bit Error Rate
- Allan Deviation
- Standard Deviation
- Power
- Phase Noise
- ...

Comment: Hello Dan. Perhaps I should ask another, more focal question such as `What are the features we must to declare a signal as digital?` (or continuous, for that matter) because I just want to understand what are the features that we **must measure** to declare a signal as "digital" or "continuous". So far, for digital, I figure that these are `time` AND `amplitude` while about "continuous" I don't know. If you think another question would be a bad idea, you might want to edit and add a new chapter (with markdown `##`) and explain what we **must measure** for each such declaration.

Comment: I believe, as my answer leads to, that there is no such requirement. It can be anything that we have a sensor for: any sensor that creates values over an independent variable (time, frequency, space etc) is a waveform. (I see that Wikipedia deifnes waveforms as having a function of time, but I argue that needn't be the case-- I know we can have frequency domain waveforms for example)

Comment: (I also see from the Talk tab in that wikipedia article that it is currently rated low quality and considered incomplete (which I just agreed with): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Waveform )

Answer (score 1):

The couple time/amplitude denotes the domains of acquisition/representation of the measurement. Discrete or continuous are properties of the measurement or how the data is stored, with what symbols, etc. One could call them **characteristics**, maybe. To me, that is the "naked" digital representation, as one manipulate them.

As for the other acquisition related **parameters**, like units (voltage, time), acquisition  settings (measurement rate, digital precision), sensor/recording settings (offset, conversion, range, calibration), sometimes stored in headers.

Frequency is more often an alternative to a time representation. However, some signals are acquired through a Fourier-like procedure (notably in spectrometry).

When I think of **features**, I instead think about other quantities derived from the signal, to obtain refined information useful to further processing. Such features are obtained  either by a determined procedure (a succession of computations) or by learning techniques. They can use any transformation (including a frequency domain) combining time or amplitude data. As features are use to describe, compare, classify, diagnose..., they often concentrate, summarize or reorder data information for some action. As we often deal with deterministic and stochastic aspects, I tend to use other distinctions, and they somehow overlap. Broadly speaking, I ask how features are:

- local or global. Example: the location of the maximum versus the value of the maximum.
- parametric or nonparametric: the best fitting slope (parametric linear modeling) versus the average of absolute discrete differences.
- unitless or with units: mean over standard deviation ratio versus total energy.
- generic or related to certain classes of signals: frequency spread versus Hurst parameter for fractal processes.

For instance, one can think about:

- statistical moments: mean, median, standard deviation, kurtosis ([higher-order cumulant and moment names beyond variance, skewness and kurtosis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/188281/83945)),
- orders and parameters from parametric models (polynonial, damped sines),
- highest-magnitude terms from some transformation of the data.